# Validating Ranges

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing a tool where user can select different options for different values of a formula.

Eg: F=value of formula

```
if (F>10) option = 1

if (F<5) option = 2

if (F=7) option = 6
```

User enter these conditions one by one. Before he enter a new condition, I need to know whether existing conditions are OK. If there are two conditions like  `F < 5` and `F = 8` it should be identified as an error.

`F > 2` and `F < 4` are OK as i can consider it as `2 < F < 4` and `F < 4`. It is OK to have uncovered ranges (can set default option).

Is there any data structure to do this or any algorithm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the user is passing in a `String` containing the expression, your best bet is to perform some `String` analysis to lighten the load. For example, if the user enters `F=6` you know nothing else can work, so you can not allow any more.

Comment: Can you add a little more context? What are error conditions and what are accepted conditions?

Comment: These look very similar to constraints in a linear optimisation. You could try using a Simplex implementation to check for feasibility.

Comment: What should happen if user inserts F < 5 and than F < 8? Should it treat as an error or second option should be treated as 5<F<8 and considered fine?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple actually, you just need to have 2 variables - `lowerBound` and `upperBound`,  which are initialized to `-infnity` and `infinity` at the start.

When a new condition arrives,

- if it is `F<a`, update: `upperBound = min{upperBound, a-1}`
- if it is `F>a`, update: `lowerBound = max{lowerBound , a+1}`
- if it is `F=a`, update: `lowerBound = max{lowerBound , a}, upperBound = min{upperBound, a}`,

If at any point `lowerBound > upperBound` - there is no solution

I assumed integers here, but it's quite easy to modify it for non-integers as well.